# Client Side Image Resizing - canvasResize add multiple file option

Tags: html5-canvas, image-resizing

canvasResize is a plugin http://www.jqueryscript.net/layout/jQuery-Plugin-for-Client-Side-Image-Resizing-canvasResize.html. and it can resizing image of client side before upload.very nice!but the sample only offer single file upload, please help me to edit to mutiple file,thanks very much!!! 
here is the single file  method code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8" />
        <title></title>
    </head>
    <body>


         <style>
                    #area div p { display: block; width: 300px; }
                    #area div p span { display: block; padding: 2px 0; width: 0; background: #193; text-align: center; }
                    #area b, #area img { display: block; }
                    #area img { margin: 10px 0; width: 300px; }
                    #area input { visibility: hidden; height: 0; }
                    #area u { display: block; padding: 15px; text-align: center; background: #ddd; border-radius: 6px; }
                </style>
            <div id="area">
              <h3>canvasResize</h3>
              <div>
                <input name="photo" type="file" multiple="multiple"/>
                <u>Choose file</u>
                <p><span></span></p>
                <i></i> </div>
              <script>

                        $().ready(function() {

                            $('#area u').click(function() {
                                $('input[name=photo]').trigger('click');
                            });

                            $('input[name=photo]').change(function(e) {
                                var file = e.target.files[0];

                                // RESET
                                $('#area p span').css('width', 0 + "%").html('');
                                $('#area img, #area canvas').remove();
                                $('#area i').html(JSON.stringify(e.target.files[0]).replace(/,/g, ", <br/>"));


// CANVAS RESIZING
                                $.canvasResize(file, {
                                    width: 800,
                                    height: 0,
                                    crop: false,
                                    quality: 80,
                                    //rotate: 90,
                                    callback: function(data, width, height) {

                                        // SHOW AS AN IMAGE
                                        // =================================================

                                        $('<img>').load(function() {

                                            $(this).css({
                                                'margin': '10px auto',
                                                'width': width,
                                                'height': height
                                            }).appendTo('#area div');

                                        }).attr('src', data);

                                        // /SHOW AS AN IMAGE
                                        // =================================================

                                        // IMAGE UPLOADING
                                        // =================================================

                                        // Create a new formdata
                                        var fd = new FormData();
                                        // Add file data
                                        var f = $.canvasResize('dataURLtoBlob', data);
                                        f.name = file.name;
                                        fd.append($('#area input').attr('name'), f);

                                        $.ajax({
                                            url: 'Page2.cshtml',
                                            type: 'POST',
                                            data: fd,
                                            dataType: 'json',
                                            contentType: false,
                                            processData: false,
                                            beforeSend: function(xhr) {
                                                xhr.setRequestHeader("pragma", "no-cache");
                                            },
                                            xhr: function() {
                                                var xhr = new window.XMLHttpRequest();
                                                //Upload progress
                                                xhr.upload.addEventListener("progress", function(e) {
                                                    if (e.lengthComputable) {
                                                        var loaded = Math.ceil((e.loaded / e.total) * 100);
                                                        $('p span').css({
                                                            'width': loaded + "%"
                                                        }).html(loaded + "%");
                                                    }
                                                }, false);
                                                return xhr;
                                            }
                                        }).done(function(response) {

                                            //console.log(response);
                                            if (response.filename) {
                                                // Complete
                                                $('#area p span').html('done');
                                                $('#area b').html(response.filename);
                                                $('<img>').attr({
                                                    'src': response.filename
                                                })
                                                        .appendTo($('#area div'));
                                            }

                                        });

                                        // /IMAGE UPLOADING
                                        // =================================================               
                                    }
                                });

                            });
                        });
                    </script> 
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.exif.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/jquery.canvasResize.js"></script>
        <script src="~/Scripts/canvasResize.js"></script>
        </div>



    </body>
        </html>
```